# How can i use a maven local repository as a remote repository?

Tags: maven, repository, settings, local

I want to change my local repository temporary and i also want to use my local repository as a remote repository.

I should be able to use mvn install -Dmaven.repo.local=temporaryDir and it should get the artifacts/dependencies from my local repository instead of downloading them again.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your (old) local repository as repository in your `settings.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Try fidging around with your maven settings file. Refer to [this article](https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/change-local-repository-location/) to find it, uncomment/edit the tags with names like "repository".

*(I found `settings.xml` in both `{MAVEN_INSTALLATION_FOLDER}/conf/` and `{USER_FOLDER}/.m2/` but I think is the last one to be applied. I guess you can find which one is on the settings of your IDE/project)*